# Regex finding 22 numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regular-expressions

So I have a database `string` which is `<@$244230034359844866> <@$244230033359844566>`. How would I make it so that when I do console.log it only shows up with `244230034359844866, 244230033359844566` 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Sagar you can create string list and then simply use replaceAll('\D','') to get only numbers from string.

```
var myStringArray = ["<@$244230034359844866>","<@$244230034359844868>"];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
 system.debug(myStringArray[i].replaceAll('\\D',''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@NotAndy, you can put the string into a list and then iterate over it to fetch the number using subString function of string. I am assuming that the string format will always be same as you mentioned above. Please find the code below for your reference-

```
var myStringArray = ["<@$244230034359844866>","<@$244230034359844868>"];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
   console.log(myStringArray[i].substring(3, 21));
}
```